# Error on calling method inside AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables, methods

I'm getting the following error: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method"

What specifically should I change to avoid it?

I'm having following AlertDialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Confirm")
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //I need some actions to be done here
            }})
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
```

I need this to be done inside AlertDialog:

```
        String st = editTextSt.getText().toString();
        String sp = editTextSp.getText().toString();
        SQLiteDbHelper database2 = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = database2.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SP, sp);
        values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ST, st);
        long insertId = database.insert(SQLiteDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a variable as `final` would mean that it's value will be fixed throughout it's life cycle. So you can't change the value of `st` and `sp`.

There is another solution.

Declare `st` and `sp` as global variables. They can then be accessed within the AlertDialog even though they're not final.

Global variables are variables declared outside any function within the class.

Example:

```
public class Example
{

String sp,st;
SQLiteDatabase database, database2;
void func()
{
 new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle("Confirm")
        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          String st = editTextSt.getText().toString();
    String sp = editTextSp.getText().toString();
    database2 = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);
    database = database2.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SP, sp);
    values.put(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ST, st);
    long insertId = database.insert(SQLiteDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }})
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();

  }
```

Now the value of sp and st can be changed and still accessed within the dialog even though they're not final.

Comment: just figured out that this "SQLiteDbHelper database2 = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);" should be under "String sp, st;", too.. thanks!.. correct it and I'll accept!

Comment: accepted! can't vote up because of low reputation. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable in question as final.

You probably just need to do final EditText editTextSt... Let me know if you have more questions. Also, if that is the case, please include the complete error message.

Comment: "final SQLiteDbHelper database2 = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);" instead of "SQLiteDbHelper database2 = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);" would make it? no errors now by doing so. still haven't tried to run it

Comment: Well let me know how it goes. On a side note, you shouldn't use hardcoded strings

Comment: Was your question solved? If so please mark as such so people like Torcellite and others arent wasting their time trying to answer.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Android, it is a specific issue with using an object directly from another class from within an anonymous class. If you are going to do this the object they are sharing **MUST** be declared as `final`.

```
class TypeA
{
 final Object t = new Object();
 new TypeB()
 {
   t ... blah
 }
}
```

In the example above TypeA is the encapsulating class of the anonymous class of TypeB, and they share any object called t:

Any reference to t (which belongs to TypeA) in this anonymous class MUST be `final`, because the current context of the class TypeB cannot be resolved to an object because its anonymous.